# How to restrict the system account of a specific windows system from accessing a drive

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs, user-accounts, file-permissions

I installed two windows 10 operating systems on my computer. For some reason, I don't want the system account of one of the windows operating systems to modify the files on this disk, and I don't want to use BitLocker on this disk.

On this system, I disabled the modification permission of this disk for the system account, but on another system, the modification permission of the system account is also disabled, but I don't want to do so! I just want to make the system account of one system unable to modify the files on this drive, but the system account of the other system can modify the files on the drive.

I tried to get the SID of the user to disable the modification permission through ACL rules, but I found that I could not get the SID of the system account (using `WMIC useraccount get name,sid`)

What shall I do?

Comment: What about unmounting the drive in Disk Manager in that instance? What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: @music2myear I can't unmount this drive. Because this instance is a VHD operating system running on this drive. In fact, this operating system running on VHD is used by me to test some dangerous software that may contain viruses, so I need to avoid it being able to modify files on the drive.

Comment: That information needs to be in the body of the question.